# Using Timba Survey - send survey when case is closed

Tags: workflow, survey

I need to have the following scenario working properly:
After a case is closed, I want the contact to receive a survey by email and capture the response. Later on use this response in a report on the dashboard.
I created a new survey using Timba surveys and I have a proper template.
Question: How do I send this survey from a WFR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a workflow rule to fire via a Closed Case.  You just have to setup the Email Alert that goes out to fire the Timba Survey's template with the Survey Link and everyting.

The link would look something like this: 'http://[mydomain].[cs#].force.com/timbasurveys__survey?id=a1KM0000002ZGDqMAO&lId='+[relatedIdofContact/Lead]+'&wf=yes')}

Comment: any ways to resend survey reminder if not submitted in 7 days with the same case Id.??